# Running shell commands from Haskell in NixOS

Tags: haskell, nixos

I'm fairly new to NixOS, and am trying to invoke emacs from a Haskell program using the following function:

```
ediff :: String -> String -> String -> IO ()
ediff testName a b = do
  a' <- writeSystemTempFile (testName ++ ".expected") a
  b' <- writeSystemTempFile (testName ++ ".received") b
  let quote s = "\"" ++ s ++ "\""
  callCommand $ "emacs --eval \'(ediff-files " ++ quote a' ++ quote b' ++ ")\'"
```

When I run the program that invokes this command using `stack test`, I get the following result (interspersed with unit test results):

```
/bin/sh: emacs: command not found
Exception: callCommand: emacs --eval '(ediff-files "/run/user/1000/ast1780695788709393584.expected" "/run/user/1000/ast4917054031918502651.received")'
```

When I run the command that failed to run above from my shell, it works flawlessly. How can I run processes from Haskell in NixOS, as though I had invoked them directly, so that they can access the same commands and configurations as my user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both your shell and `callCommand` use the `PATH` environment variable, so it seems like stack is changing that. It turns out that stack uses a pure nix shell by default, but you also want to access your user environment, which is 'impure'.

To quote the [stack documenation](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/v1.0.2/nix_integration/#the-nix-shell)

> By default, stack will run the build in a pure Nix build environment (or shell), which means the build should fail if you haven't specified all the dependencies in the packages: section of the stack.yaml file, even if these dependencies are installed elsewhere on your system. This behaviour enforces a complete description of the build environment to facilitate reproducibility. To override this behaviour, add pure: false to your stack.yaml or pass the --no-nix-pure option to the command line.

Another solution is to add Emacs to `nix.dependencies` in `stack.yaml` (thanks @chepner). It has the benefit that some version of Emacs will always be available when a developer runs the tests, but that Emacs may not be the Emacs they want to use. You may be able to work around that using something like `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`, unless they have configured their Emacs elsewhere, like the system configuration or perhaps a home manager. I'd prefer the simple but impure `$PATH` solution.

Comment: The solution would be to add `emacs` to the dependency list, though, rather than using an impure environment, right?

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had time to use your suggestions just yet, but this is very informative.